# Complications with designing a new web site from scratch as an individual

Tags: html, css, web

I was trying to create my own website for educational reasons. I was trying to do this from scratch with the best of intentions and trying to follow the latest theories in web design, but it was too much to absorb for one person in isolation.

I got some useful hints to start but went away and scrapped my web site and returned to the drawing board to work out how better to proceed using an already existing system dedicated to the latest in thinking on best practice in web design and to look deeper into the value of using a scripting system to manage encapsulation. See my answer for the conclusion, for those of you, who, like me, are building a web site on your own.

Comment: What do you mean for ugly? Are you talking about horizontal bar?

Comment: KIndly share your css.

Comment: @YouKnowNothingJonSnow Click on the link and do your browser's version of Show Page Source.

Comment: @marianoc84 If you go to my website and shrink the page horizontally then scroll the page with the horizontal scroll bar the redrawing is all messed up.

Comment: GeoffPointer I can't reach the linked css file @import "maths_blog.css";

Comment: @YouKnowNothingJonSnow Go to maths.geoffpointer.com in your browser and then show page source.

Comment: Your page structure is pretty elementary and you don't for the loe of God have to deal with the sort of css you have.Go to getbootstrap.com and get yourself twitter bootstrap.After seeing several absolute positions in your css file,i gave up fixing it.

Comment: Here is an example of your page layout in twitter bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/Gf4CD/1/show/ and the source http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/Gf4CD/1/

Comment: @YouKnowNothingJonSnow That's just my home page. I've only just started. Eventually, inside Maths and LaTeX - with a section on Physics coming later on -  there will be many topics, within each topic, many articles, within many of the articles, many pages, which is why I want the menu on the left hand side and why I'm trying to find a structure that will make a large amount of content accessible as easily as possible.

Comment: @GeoffPointer The layout i wrote you takes care of that,for instance http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/Gf4CD/4/show/ and for the source http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/Gf4CD/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the complications of web design:
(1) Use an existing system like Bootstrap - don't reinvent the wheel. You can add your own originality by the way in which you use it and with some final css touches that give the site your own signature. Bootsrap is built by a dedicated team of developers with all the latest design principles built in.
(2) Use some kind of server side include system supported by some kind of scripting language. I personally recommend using a javascript object data structure to contain the unique per page detail. Each page is unique and bookmarkable, so there's no need to have its unique data stored separately. The design I used aimed at eliminating as much repetition as possible and the beauty of javascript data structures is that their form can vary from page to page and yet only require one function to handle them. Thus, for each page, you only need to put in the data that page needs.

Conclusion: This question was probably going to grow until it became unwieldy with one complication leading to another. The main problem I had was trying to design my web site from scratch. I thought I was doing the right thing by trying to absorb as much of the current global thinking about web design, but the situation has become too complicated for one person to attempt to start from the beginning.

An answer to my structure woes was hinted at in the comments, but I had to dig underneath to find it. Having now discovered the Bootstrap system I can highly recommend it. It enabled me to rebuild my entire website in no time and automatically incorporates all the responsiveness I need. The answer to my encapsulation woes was suggested via javascript, although I don't like the mustache idea, so I was pushed into investigating javascript in greater depth. The solution I'm now using is a combination of SSI and a flexible javascript object type data structure to handle the unique detail of individual pages.

My new site is [here](http://maths.geoffpointer.com). It works really well on a desktop computer and an iPhone alike. I've included a copy of the code of one of my pages below that shows the entire page is loaded via SSI from template files and its detail is filled in using a javascript function activated when the page loads. Now, when I add a new page, all I have to do is create the new content and then fill in its data structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!--#include virtual="/main_head.htm" -->

    <script>
      var detail = {
        type: 'book', brand: 'Maths', title: 'Pythagorean Triples 1&amp;2',
        article: {subject: 'maths', topic: 'number_theory',
          title: 'pythag_paper', page: 'pythag_paper_a.shtml'},
        read: { state: 'active', link: ''},
        list: { state: '', link: ''},
        fill: {left: 'images/pythag_paper_01.png', right: 'images/pythag_paper_02.png'},
        step: [
             {state: 'disabled', link: ''},
             {state: 'disabled', link: ''},
             {state: 'active', link: 'pythag_paper_b.shtml'},
             {state: 'active', link: 'pythag_paper_d.shtml'}
             ]
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="setBookDetail()">

    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
    <div id="wrap">

      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <!--#include virtual="/main_navbar.htm" -->

      <!-- Begin page content -->
      <div class="container">
        <!--#include virtual="/main_title.htm" -->
        <!--#include virtual="/main_page.htm" -->
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Sticky footer -->
    <!--#include virtual="/main_footer.htm" -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your your problem was about the ugly horizontal bar. Since I don't like that type of include. I would resolve start using a template engine like [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), that works in Javascript, so you don't need a server side scripting language.

For example, you can place a template inside `script` tags::

```
<script type="text/x-mustache" id="template">
    <p>Hello, {{name}}</p>
</script>
```

and access the contents of that script tag with jQuery:

```
var temp = $("#template").html();
Mustache.render(temp { name: "Jack" });
// returns: <p>Hello, Jack</p>
```

And after this, take a look at [responsive Web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used to write my pages using frames in order to reuse structure for the usual reasons. Then W3C deprecated frames. Using tables to structure pages is also frowned upon (although extensively employed on the web). They want every page to be bookmarkable which is fair enough, so I'm trying to create a web site using up to date css, but with as much generic structure as possible, so I'm not repeating masses of code.

Comment: So take a look at responsive web design (as I suggest in my edit).

Comment: (1) You say you don't like SSI, but that's part of RWD. What's wrong with SSI? (2) Are you answering my indirect questions here or are you saying that includes are the reason I have the page redraw problem?

Comment: Redraw problem is about the lack of a responsive layout (read the linked wikipedia page as a start). I prefear Js template solution cause this best fit contingent Js scripts, and I found it easy to debug. But nothing is wrong with SSI, even if in past time it was a great fault on the server side sometimes.